Is a cryptosystem based on hardness of factorization of polynomials, as defined below valid?
I'm proposing a cryptosystem as defined below:

Private Key: $(R, A, R^{-1})$, where $R = \left(\mathbf{r_1}, \cdots, \mathbf{r_n}\right)$ is full-rank, with $n \geq 4$, even; $A = \left(a_1\mathbf{e_1}, \cdots, a_n\mathbf{e_n} \right)$ and $a_i \neq 0$;
Public Key: $B = RAR^{-1}$;
Plaintext: $P \in \mathbb{F}_p^{n\times n}$ represents an ordered basis over $\mathbb{F}_p^n$;
Ciphertext: $C = PBP^{-1}$;
Decription: $VR^{-1}$, where $V = \left(\mathbf{v_1}, \cdots, \mathbf{v_n}\right)$, where $C\mathbf{v_i} = a_i\mathbf{v_i}$;
Document: $d \in \mathbb{F}_p$;
Signature: $s = \Pi_{i = 1}^{n/2} (x-a_{\pi(i)}^d) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$, where $\pi(\cdot) \in S_n$;
Verification: $s | b_d$, where $b_d = det\left(B^d-xI\right) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$;

where:

$\mathbb{F}_p$ refers to the finite field of order $p$;
$\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ refers to the set of polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_p$;
$\left(\mathbf{m_1},\cdots,\mathbf{m_n}\right)$ signifies a matrix having $\mathbf{m_i}$ as its $i$th column vector;
$\mathbf{e_i}$ refers to the $i$th canonical vector of $\mathbb{F}_p$;
$p|q$ means '$p$ divides $q$';
$S_n$ is the symmetric group of $n$ elements;

Is it original?
Is the premise of soundess based on hardness of factorization of polynomials over finite fields valid?
References: White Paper

Review of designs is normally considered off topic. there are probably better places to ask, but you may get comments here.

Isn't factorization of polynomials in a finite field possible in polynomial time for practical purposes?
